# Prove thar for every number $n\in \mathbb N$ there exists a number such that

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a number $m$ such that $m\equiv 0\pmod n$, $m$ is composed of only 1's and 0's and the number $m$ is of length $\leq n$. For example, for $n=3$ the number is $m=111=37\cdot 3$ and for $n=7,$ the number is $111111=15873\cdot 7.$

Any ideas?

Edit: I forgot to add something in my original question, added it now.

Edit: reformulated by CiaPan.

Comment: Prove with induction? 10*x + 1 as induction step?

Comment: `of length ≤n` If that's $\le$ indeed, then the number $1$ will work for $\forall n$.

Comment: What kind of question is this? Sorry if I sound rude, but this seems nonsensical at best, what's the source?

Comment: Presumably, it should read "for every number n∈N there exists a **multiple** such that the number is of length $\le n$ and is composed of only 1s and 0s". The examples are consistent with it, and it wouldn't be too easy. Though for $n=7,$ the multiple $1001$ would be shorter.

Comment: I forgot to add something to the question, added it now

Answer (score 1):

Consider the numbers 
$$0, 1, 11, 111, \dots , 111\dots 1$$ 
where the last one has $n$ ones. Then by [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) two of these $(n+1)$ numbers have the same remainder when divided by $n$.
Take their difference and we obtain a number of the form  $111\dots 000$ which has a number of digits $\leq n$ and it is divisible by $n$.

Comment: Why add the $1$?

Comment: @MarkBennet Why add the $10^{n-1}$ ;-) until the OP fixes their question, that is.

Comment: @dxiv Indeed. And OP has shown a viable approach with $(10^n-1)/9$. It is a curious question, and I think will likely be clarified.

Comment: I forgot to add something to the question lol, I didn't realize it untill now, fixed it though

Comment: @sssss I edited my answer for your modified question.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is coprime to $30$, then we have $$10^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$$

(where $\phi(n)$ is the totient-function) due to Euler's theorem. Hence, we have $$n|\frac{10^{\phi(n)}-1}{9}$$ Hence, $n$ divides the number consisting of $\phi(n)$ ones. Because of $\phi(n)<n$, we have the desired number.

If $n|m$ , then the number formed by concanating $m$ three times, is divisible by $3n$ and since the length is multiplied by $3$, the length keeps short enough. So, we also can manage $3^k\cdot n$

Finally, if we multiply $n$ coprime to $10$ with $2^a\cdot 5^b$ , we add $\max(a,b)$ zeros and have a number short enough divisible by $2^a\cdot 5^b\cdot n$